# The import org.apache.commons.net cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

Why am I getting this error? I already imported the jar file in my eclipse project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add it to your project's build path.

Comment: But if I do import org.apache.commons.*; then there is no error. Why is that? All the apache common jar files are in the same directory

Comment: @mrburns: "But if I do import org.apache.commons.*; then there is no error. Why is that?" -- perhaps you only have one of the JARs in your build path.